# How to make id user can be view content

Tags: custom-post-types, author

I have code

```
<?php
global $current_user; // Use global
get_currentuserinfo(); // Make sure global is set, if not set it.
if ( ! user_can( $current_user, "subscriber" ) ) // Check user object has not got subscriber role
    echo '<span>if user, can view post content</span>';
else
    echo '<span>if no user, can not view</span>';

?>
```

How to make

```
echo '<span>if user, can view post content</span>';
```

=> i try it, but no active :(

```
echo '<span><div class="col-sm-12">
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>  

<p>

<a class="btn btn-success">Tồng số chữ : <?php if(function_exists('bac_post_word_count')) { bac_post_word_count(); }?></a>
  <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="<?php 
  $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'download' );
  if( !empty($meta) ) {
    echo $meta[0];
  }
?>" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span> Tải về .docx</a></p>



<?php the_content(); ?>


  </div></span>';
```

Answer (score 0):

WP no longer uses role names in this type of function. You need to use

```
if(current_user_can($capability)) {
```

where `$capability` is a capability like `read_posts`, `publish_posts`, etc. and not the name of a role like `subscriber` or `editor`.